# Set title for Tiles pages in Spring MVC Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, struts2, tiles

I'm using Tiles 3 with Spring MVC 3.2. Following is the code

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definition" template="/pages/Layout/Layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Setting Title" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/pages/Layout/Footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="*" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/{1}.jsp" />
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

By using the above code I could get same structure to multiple pages. But just wondering if I could set title for each page without writing different definitions in tiles.xml. **In such a case can I directly control title from Content page?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can directly send content via model.addAttribute("title", "Hello"); from Spring controller. I though it would not work on layout page. But it would work there also

Comment: Does anyone know how do do it from the view rather than the controller? I feel like page title ought to be defined by the view rather than by a controller or model. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539517/change-page-title-from-spring-mvc-velocity-view

Comment: @Ryan in view u can set the title easily by using '<title></title>' tags

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't the approach I'm looking for (please see my comment in response to Greg Case http://stackoverflow.com/a/18541739/470749).