# Change page title from Spring MVC Velocity view?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I feel like page title ought to be defined by the view rather than by a controller or model.

In Zend Framework, I could write this in the view:
`$this->headTitle('Signup');`

And that would change the page's window title to 'Signup'.

How can I do that in Java Spring MVC using Velocity for the view?

I thought maybe I could use something like:

`$page.setTitle("Signup")`

but it didn't work.

This is probably similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539645/how-to-set-head-meta-tag-from-view-layer-in-spring-mvc-velocity

P.S. I'm also using Apache Tiles, so I have a Velocity file for layout.vm (which creates the HTML, HEAD, BODY, etc) and a Velocity file for signup.vm (which just creates the signup form).  I want to be able to specify within signup.vm what the page's title should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your velocity view is generating all of the HTML that is sent to the browser.  You just add a `<title>` element to your page.

**SignupController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signUp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView signup() {
    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("sign_up");
    modelView.setObect("personName", "The Dude");
    return modelView;
}
```

**sign_up.vm**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Signup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Looks like you are signing up for something, ${personName}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified in my question that I'm using Apache Tiles, so the <head><title>xxx</title></head> code isn't accessible from where I'm coding this velocity template for this particular view.  This view file is just the "content" that is inserted into the layout.  I'll mention this in the question.